# Deploying software that requires X.509 certificates

Tags: wcf, certificate, x509certificate, x509, certificate-authority

I have a self-hosted WCF application, with a server application running on the server (obviously) and a client application that will be installed on the users PC. Up until this point I have been developing the system on my personal machine and using "development" x.509 certificates and all works fine. I am comfortable with how certificate authentication works etc. but what I am stuck on is how do I deploy the client-side software with the required certificates?

FYI: the application uses TCP not HTTP.

I wish to use the active directory certification authority setup on the server.. but to be honest I can't get my head around how deployment is going to work? I have seen one tutorial that requires IIS to be setup and uses http to request the certificate manually (or something along those lines). But I don't want to setup IIS solely for that purpose... or is that my only option?

Also, regarding the client application that will be distributed using ClickOnce, will users need to manually acquire the certificate prior to installation or can this process be automated?

I am sorry if these questions come across as "newbie", but I have researched this for a couple hours and have not found anything that gives me clarity on this subject! I am prepared to make this work in whatever way deemed necessary... but what is necessary?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think there's too much to this question for anyone to give you a useful answer. You're asking about infrastructure, architecture, deployment and implementation (all rolled into one). Have you tried reading a book like [Windows Server 2008 PKI and Certificate Security](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735625166)?

Comment: @noloader - no I haven't, but I will, thanks for the direction!